# asp.net uploading files over a Gig in file size?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

Is there some open source file upload (application) solution for a scenario like this?  We have users who might want to upload really giant files, could be several GB's in file size in fact, and it seems like a regular file upload textbox isn't going to be a good choice here due to timeouts, etc...

Thanks for any advice...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jon Galloway has a good article here: [Large file uploads in ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx)

He mentions **NeatUpload** (which is free, and posted under the LGPL, a business-friendly open source license) in the article, and the link to the codeplex page: http://neatupload.codeplex.com/

> **Project Description**
>
> The NeatUpload ™ ASP.NET component allows developers to stream
>   uploaded files to storage (filesystem or database) and allows users to
>   monitor upload progress. It is open source and works under Mono's
>   XSP/mod_mono as well as Microsoft's ASP.NET implementation.
>
> It features several custom controls, including:
>
> - MultiFile allows all users to select multiple files to upload and
>     allows Flash 8+ users to select multiple files from a single file
>     selection dialog.
> - ProgressBar displays the upload progress either inline or in a popup.
> - UnloadConfirmer prevents users from accidentally interrupting an upload by leaving the page.
>
> **Features**
>
> - Works in web gardens and web farms.
> - Works under medium trust environments when installed in the GAC.
> - Works under Mono's XSP/mod_mono and Microsoft's ASP.NET 1.1 or higher.
> - Easy to install and use. Add the UploadHttpModule to the   section of your Web.config
>     and drag-and-drop the controls using the Visual Studios Web Forms
>     Designer.
> - ProgressBar control can display processing progress in
>     addition to upload progress.
> - ProgressBar control uses AJAX-style
>     refreshless updates on modern browsers when JavaScript is available,
>     but also allows users without JavaScript to see upload progress.
> - Allows customization through styles, custom progress display pages,
>     UploadStorageProviders, and UploadStateStoreProviders, and provides an
>     API for creating your own file upload and progress controls.
> - Falls back to using ASP.NET's HttpPostedFile if the NeatUpload UploadHttpModule is not present. This makes it easy to remove the
>     HttpModule if for some reason it causes problems.
> - Streams uploads directly to storage. This conserves server memory, allows larger uploads, and helps prevent Denial of Service attacks.
> - Removes uploaded files when an error occurs. This helps prevent disk space leakage.
> - Licensed under the Lesser General Public License (LGPL), a business-friendly open source license.