# Upload large file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload

I want to upload 30GB with asp.net file upload control, i have heard that ftp can do this or some advanced uploader. I searched but did not find any suitable code or some open source plugin for asp.net. Do you know some library or whats the right way to do this, i am confused. 
I am in search of ASP.Net file upload which could upload large file e.g 30GB, and with any logic like ftp or some other resuming way. So is there any plugin which can do this job?

Comment: Please make your question more clear: you've listed 3 ways to upload a file (browser's file upload element, FTP and some "uploader with resume feature"). Also show some effort to search for suitable answer... otherwise your question may be simply closed...

Comment: Have you looked into http://upload.thinfile.com/features.php?

Comment: Suspect duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386866/asp-net-uploading-files-over-a-gig-in-file-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this. Many browsers have upload limit ~ 2GB. Think about different solution than HTTP POST, e.g. direct FTP upload.

Comment: Looks like the 2GB limit applies to IE, not Chrome or Firefox. http://neatupload.codeplex.com/discussions/233201

Comment: Possible. Some time ago I think it was the case for all browsers. There are also limits set on the server side, which you should be aware of especially if you cannot change the server configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pretty good writeup of the problem
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx

In my own experience working with gigabyte uploads in .net several years ago, it is not easy within the common controls and infrastructure. You will be fighting http timeouts, and have to adjust the web.config to allow for the file size and changes a bit in web.config.

What has to happen to make it work is some form of chunking. So you divide the file up into much smaller pieces and then attempt to upload each one. Then you will have to keep track of which pieces you have gotten and which you have not.

A better/easier solution is to add some RIA functionality to your application so you can handle the upload in

Answer (score 0):

You could try NeatUpload http://neatupload.codeplex.com/. I've used it last time for uploading files as large as 10MB without problems. Never tried it with multi GB files though.

The control requires full trust.

Comment: Small print: Considering that input type=file chokes on files smaller than 4MB =)

Comment: It should not. Maybe it's a bad server configuration?

Comment: 4MB is the default file size limit set in ASP.NET. Increasing the limit doesn't help much, since the user doesn't get feedback on the file upload progress and might just close the browser window. That's why I ended up using NeatUpload, which has its own file size limit settings. (I *might* have uploaded some 100MB files using NeatUpload taking several minutes)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best should be WebDAV server engine approach http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/large_files_iis_asp_net